# Extracting string from Regex in Pandas for large dataset

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

We have a csv file which contains log entries in each row.
We need to extract the thread names from each log entry into a separate column.

What would be the fastest way to implement the same ?

The approach below (string functions) also seems to take alot of time for large datasets.

We have csv files with minimum of 100K entries in each csv file.

This is the piece of codes which extracts the path

```
df['thread'] = df.message.str.extract(pat = '(\[(\w+.)+?\]|$)')[0]
```

The below is a sample log entry, we are picking out:

```
[c.a.j.sprint_planning_resources.listener.RunAsyncEvent]
```

from the regex above.

```
2020-12-01 05:07:36,485-0500 ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-30 WARN Ives_Chen 245x27568399x23 oxk7fv 10.97.200.99,127.0.0.1 /browse/MDT-206838 [c.a.j.sprint_planning_resources.listener.RunAsyncEvent] Event processed:  com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent@5c8703d0[issue=ABC-61381,comment=<null>,worklog=<null>,changelog=[GenericEntity:ChangeGroup][issue,1443521][author,JIRAUSER39166][created,2020-12-01 05:07:36.377][id,15932782],eventTypeId=2,sendMail=true,params={eventsource=action, baseurl=https://min.com},subtasksUpdated=true,spanningOperation=Optional.empty]
```

Does anyone know a better/faster method to implement the same ?

Comment: `\[(\w+.)+?\]` is a very inefficient pattern that may cause catastrophic backtracking. You must use `\[(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)]`

Answer (score 2):

The `\[(\w+.)+?\]` is a very inefficient pattern that may cause catastrophic backtracking due to the nested quantifiers with an unescaped `.` that matches any char, and thus also matches what `\w` does.

You can use

```py
df['thread'] = df['message'].str.extract(r'\[(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)]', expand=False).fillna("")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovlLMN/1). Note there is no need adding `$` as an alternative since `.fillna("")` will replace the `NA` with an empty string.

The regex matches

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars followed with zero or more sequences of a `.` and one or more word chars
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Thank you, you were right my regex was inefficient. Tried your solution, it finished quickly. The timeit output is the following for 140K rows
426 ms ± 44.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex takes a whopping 8,572 steps to complete, see https://regex101.com/r/5c3vi7/1

You can use this regex to significantly cut down the regex processing to 4 steps:

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

Do notice the absence of the `/g` modifier

https://regex101.com/r/6522P8/1

Comment: Thank you, you were right my regex was inefficient. Tried your solution as well, it finished quickly. The timeit output is the following for 140K rows
1.03 s ± 62.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
However, slight modification had to be made to the regex

df['thread'] = df.message.str.extract(pat = '((?<!\[)\[[^]]+\])')

Comment: @ShreyanceShaw Why are you not escaping the `[`? That should be creating issues for you.

Comment: @ShreyanceShaw I've cut the regex down to 4 steps now. See the update.

Comment: Yes works better now, 269 ms ± 16.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) for 140K rows.

Comment: @ShreyanceShaw Wow, more efficient than Wiktor's answer? I never thought I would see the day :')

Comment: Curiously, what was your initial benchmark with your regex?

Comment: There was no initial benchmark since the earlier regex didn't finish at all. That being said, while it did perform better with respect to Wiktor's regex, it did not however properly pick all the required thread names from a variety of logs.. on that front the other regex did a better job.

Comment: @ShreyanceShaw I see, you only provided a single log example though. It's fairly impossible for us to guess your variety of logs.

Comment: Yes you are right, just mentioning that. however, your solutions works.. very well on majority of the data.